# Android activity being killed, how to make it run indefinitely

Tags: java, android

I have an App that works analoguely to an digital photo frame.
It works exhibiting a static site , just a webview showing  a local HTML.
I want it to run undefinetely, i already acquired the wakelock but it seens that after sometime the application keeps getting killed.
How i prevent android from killing my long runnin activity?

Comment: Have you checked LogCat? What does it say about the kill reason?

Comment: What do you mean by getting killed?  Is it a crash or does it go to background after a while?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it on debug mode or simulator yet. It doesn't go to background.I have the wakelock, prevent blocking and it's running on a encased tablet so no buttons are pressed.

Comment: Code Droid, it shows the message, "The application (foo) has stopped unexpecdly, please try again" and force quit. But it doesn't make any processing besides the webView

Comment: Ok. So it did crash. Should try to run in debug mode view logcat to see the specific error.  Look for red writing and the word 'fatal'

Comment: Yeah i started debugging on the device again to see if i can reproduce it.Thanks for all the feedback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should.

1) Probably have a running Service.
2) Use an AlarmManager/Receiver to guarantee there is periodic activity.
3) Start the service as sticky.
4) understand that android is the 800 lb. gorilla and if it wants to shut
   down your app it can.

Comment: Will try it. For a dum service just to keep it active

Comment: +1 for  android is the 800 lb. gorilla and if it wants to shut down your app it can.

Comment: The alarmManager solved my issue. Now a new problem arrived, how i make the alarmManager send something to my running activity? Should i use inter proccess communication? Something within the service?

Comment: You can use a BroadcastReceiver and pass the broadcasted intent to the Activity using startActivity().  This might call onCreate() or onStart() in the Activity where you can getIntent() so also overload onStart() to check. You could also pass parameters in the intent. Optionally you can register the Activity as the Broadcast receiver but I think a separate BroadCastReciever is probably better. This class is only avail for milliseconds and just forwards intents.